# Connect to hidden (non-broadcast) network using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, wifi, uwp

I am looking for a way to connect to a non-broadcast (hidden) network via C#.  This is a new area of development for me.  It is a UWP application that needs to be able to manage WiFi connections.  I am currently using the Windows.Devices.Wifi namespace to do pretty much everything else, but I don't know how to do the non-broadcast.  I have the SSID and the password for the network.  I might be missing something, and it could be really easy to do, but I am missing something.  Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter

Answer (score 1):

You can use bssid to get the WiFiAvailableNetwork like I have done:-

await wifiAdapter.ScanAsync();
var wifiList= wifiList.AddRange(wifiAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.ToList());

WiFiAvailableNetwork  targetWifi = wifiList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Bssid.Equals("00:19:a9:7f:08:a0"));

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter), this can be done with the WiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync method.

```
public IAsyncOperation<WiFiConnectionResult> ConnectAsync(
  WiFiAvailableNetwork availableNetwork, 
  WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind, 
  PasswordCredential passwordCredential, 
  string ssid
)
```

> Connect this Wi-Fi device to a hidden network, with the given passphrase and reconnection policy.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a WiFiAvailableNetwork.  And I don't think you can create one.  Unless you know how?