# C# Connect to a hidden WiFi - UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, wifi

Closest to my problem was [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348699/connect-to-hidden-non-broadcast-network-using-c) but he was downvoted and no one really helped him. I'm aware of all of the functionality that exists on MSDN using WiFiAvailableNetwork and WiFiAdapter classes. I know you need a WiFiAvailableNetwork, a PasswordCredential, and then the ssid of the hidden network. My question is:

Are you supposed to somehow find out which WiFiAvailable network corresponds to the hidden one? If so, how? Are you supposed to create a new one?

EDIT:

Best answer from the thread specified in comments. X-POST.

If available, the hidden network should be in the firstAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks list.

As the SSID is hidden, the Ssid property of WiFiAvailableNetwork for the target network will be "".

You could make an assumption here and attempt to connect to it using:

```
await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(networks.First(x => x.Ssid == ""), WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic, "password", "knownSSID");
```

Comment: I am not sure about UWP but to connect to a hidden network you need to know its SSID. Also you can create XML profile and connect using profile.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I know the SSID, but the first parameter of the ConnectAsync method is a WiFiAvailableNetwork. Do I just leave that null and fill in the rest of the parameters?

Comment: Actualy I do not use WinRT WiFi API, its better to use Native WiFi API that gives much more features.

Comment: Does this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836761/7254781) solve your problem ?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew Yes it does! Godsend!